# How many cubes must be randomly selected to ensure that at least one pair of each color has been removed from the bag?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

There are $15$ red, $11$ blue and $13$ green cubes in a bag. All cubes are identical, except for color. How many cubes must be randomly selected to ensure that at least one **pair** of each color has been removed from the bag?

Thought it should be $11 + 13 + 2 = 26$, but the answer turns out to be $30$ (cubes)... How's that so?

Comment: If you take out $29=15+13+1$ then a pair of blue can still lack.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with probability.

Answer (score 1):

Since cubes are drawn from the bag until a pair of each color have been selected, the worst case scenario is that all $15$ red cubes, all $13$ green cubes, and one blue cube are selected before the second blue cube is selected.  Thus, $15 + 13 + 1 = 29$ cubes can be selected before a second blue cube is selected.  At that point, only blue cubes remain in the bag, so the next selection will be blue.  Hence, to ensure that at least one pair of each color has been removed from the bag, we must select at least $30$ cubes.

Assume $30$ cubes are selected.  Since any selection of $30$ cubes can have at most $11$ blue cubes and at most $13$ green cubes, the number of red cubes selected is at least $30 - (11 + 13) = 6$.   Since any selection of $30$ cubes can have at most $11$ blue cubes and at most $15$ red cubes, the number of green cubes selected is at least $30 - (11 + 15) = 4$.  Since any selection of $30$ cubes can have at most $13$ green cubes and $15$ red cubes, the number of blue cubes selected is at least $30 - (13 + 15) = 2$.  Thus, we need to select at most $30$ cubes to ensure that at least two of each color have been selected.

Comment: You've shown that the answer is greater than $29$, but in a contest setting, your proof that $30$ is the true answer would probably not get a full score. For that you would need to show that _any_ selection of $30$ cubes contains at least two red cubes, at least two green cubes, and at least two blue cubes, not just the one selection where you've avoided blue cubes for as long as possible. I know it's trivial, but it's the kind of thing that would give point deduction (if you're supposed to hand in a full solution, that is).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $30$,because if you  want to ensure that at least one pair of each color has been removed from the bag you must take $\color{red}{15}$ red+ $\color{green}{13}$ green +$\color{blue}2$ blue